# fromEvent from rxjs is not working as expected

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have created a component with a search functionality which calls api and displays data over the page. Once I get the search result, I store them in localStorage to restore the data once you navigate back to the same search component page. Everything is working fine until I assign the stored data back to the formEvent observable result property this.searchResult$ . The issue is fromEvent doesn't trigger any more once I return to the same page via other routes.

```
  ngOnInit() {
 const searchEvent$ = fromEvent<any>(this.inputSearch.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(tap(() => { console.log('working'); }));
    this.searchResult$ = searchEvent$
      .pipe(
        tap(() => { this.isDataOn = true }),
        map(event => event.target.value),
        filter(value => value ? true : false),
        switchMap(search => this.notesService.onSearchNotes(search)))
      )
 if (!this.isDataOn) {
      this.refreshData()
    }
}
refreshData() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("queryStack")) {
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("queryStack") || "[]");
      console.log(data);
      this.searchResult$ = of(data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're replacing `searchResult$` with a different observable with `of(data)`. So it's not going to emit anything else afterwards.

Comment: So please tell me how to place the restored data so it could reflect in the template with the same async pipe

Comment: I don't want to call http for the previous search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach, which merges in whatever saved data you have in local storage with the results fetched from the server in response to keyup events.

```
// in your imports
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

ngOnInit() {
    const searchEvent$ = fromEvent<any>(this.inputSearch.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(tap(() => { console.log('working'); }));
    this.searchResult$ = merge(
        of(this.getSavedData()),
        searchEvent$
            .pipe(
                map(event => event.target.value),
                filter(Boolean),
                debounceTime(1000),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                switchMap(search => this.notesService.onSearchNotes(search))
            )
    );
}
getSavedData() {
    const localStorageValue = localStorage.getItem("queryStack") || "[]";
    try {
        return JSON.parse(localStorageValue);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error('Error parsing JSON:', ex);
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help @GregL  your solution is so elegant and really worked for me